# Convert LINQ query to List

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

Here is function, that I use the list of permutations:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            if (list.Count() == 1)
                return new List<IEnumerable<T>> { list };

            return list.Select((a, i1) => Permute(
                            list.Where((b, i2) => i2 != i1)).Select(
                                    b => (new List<T> { a }).Union(b))
                            ).SelectMany(c => c);
        }
```

use it in the following way:

```
var SFP_vars = Permute(SFP);
```

Where SFP is array of bytes:

```
byte[] SFP = new byte[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

There is other variable:

```
List<byte[]> lst_SFP = new List<byte[]>();
```

Now my question: How to assign the value of SFP_vars to lst_SFP ?
`lst_SFP = SFP_vars.ToList()` doesn't work.

Comment: "`lst_SFP = SFP_vars.ToList()` doesn't work" isn't the best description of your actual problem.

Comment: @spender: That will yield a "Cannot convert `List<IEnumerable<byte>>` to `List<byte[]>`" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also convert the inner enumerables to `byte` arrays:

```
lst_SFP = SFP_vars.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst_SFP = SFP_vars.Select(bytePermutation => bytePermutation.ToArray()).ToList()
```

Basically you want the things in your list to be a byte array, so the `Select` statement handles that, giving you an `IEnumerable<byte[]>`.
Then we do `ToList` on that to make it a list.

`bytePermutation` could be named anything, I just named it as such so you can get an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

SFP_vars looks like an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>>` rather than an `IEnumerable<byte[]>`.

This means that the you first need to convert the `IEnumerable<byte>` objects to `byte[]` using the ToArray() method. You can then add them to the list.

Although it amounts to the same thing, you could replace with this LINQ query:

```
List<byte[]> lst_SFP = SFP_vars.Select(ie => ie.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the inner `IEnumerable<byte>` into an array, this can be done using [`.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb548891.aspx). One this is done `.ToList()` will return as a `List<byte[]>`.

```
var SFP = new byte[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var SFP_vars = Permute(SFP);
var lst_SFP = SFP_vars
    .Select(e => e.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Unless you need a particular order though, you may be better off using the `List<IEnumerable<byte>>`. Using this will prevent an [Array.Copy](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx&ei=A-NnUY2bII6RigeP3oD4BQ&usg=AFQjCNH7IGghwH0GgJp8ErFKkeixv2KEyg&bvm=bv.45175338,d.aGc).